# Database Automation and Continuous Integration

Tags: database, automation

I have following use cases and am looking for some DB tools.

- There are 3 application deployment environments (Dev, Test, Prod) and each has its own database. If any modification in a DB (create new colomn/table or insert new records) is made in Dev, the same changes need to be made in the rest of DB environments (based on some condition)
- If a DB/schema is created in Dev newly, then data should be populated automatically for all tables - according to the relationships data types - Just sample data is enough so that developers do not need to insert manually.  Meaningless values are fine (column called client_name can have a value like  "sdgilksdgils").
- Need a track of DB changes

Once browsed I found Liquibase also its Datical, redgate. Are they suitable for my requirements or what could be possible tools ? I prefer Open Source.